# I want to 301 redirect a part of an url, but not the childeren of the url

Tags: .htaccess, url-routing, http-status-code-301

For an example:

www.domain.com/part1/part2 has to be 201,
but if you type www.domain.com/part1 it has to be redirected to www.domain.com.

The normal redirect works by part2 aswell.

Comment: Just a helpful suggestion, you might want to post what server technology (ie IIS, PHP, Apache, etc) you are using.

Comment: @Tejs: Good point, but it could be inferred from context: `.htaccess` is Apache-specific.

Comment: I use PHP on a Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to redirect if there is not a second-level to the path, you should be able to use the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule part1$ / [L,R=301]
```

Hope this helps.